# How to solve captcha in Imacros by API

Tags: captcha, imacros

I want to use deathbycaptcha to solve captchas in Imacros.

I see api for imacros, but it isnot working for me.

> http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=imagegroup&print_format=html

what I am doing:

1. submit user name and password
2. chose a picture
3. click send

but result is -1

can anyone help me?

**This is their API**

```
VERSION BUILD=844

URL GOTO=http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=imagegroup&print_format=html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT={{YOUR_DBC_USERNAME}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT={{YOUR_DBC_PASSWORD}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT={{PATH_TO_MAIN_IMAGE}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:banner CONTENT={{PATH_TO_BANNER_IMAGE}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:banner_text CONTENT={{BANNER_TEXT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:grid CONTENT={{GRID}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=*

TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
```

**This is my code in imacros**

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
FILEDELETE NAME=C:\captcha\captcha1.jpg 
URL GOTO=https://www.jayde.com/submit-site.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:jayde-url-submit ATTR=SRC:https://rservice.ientry.com/captcha.srv
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\captcha\ FILE=captcha1.jpg 

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:jayde-url-submit ATTR=HREF:"https://rservice.ientry.com/captcha.srv" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM 
tab open 
tab t=2
URL GOTO=http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=imagegroup&print_format=html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=myusername
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=C:\captcha\captcha1.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=TYPE:submit
Wait seconds=20
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
tab close
Tab t=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:HUMAN-TEST CONTENT={{VAR1}}
```

Comment: what on earth has this to do with c#

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)